# New way to port and verify on Google Voice?

Tags: google-voice

I'm trying to port my Sprint number to Google Voice (and close my Sprint account). Several [tutorials](http://lifehacker.com/5794553/how-to-port-your-number-to-google-voice-without-paying-an-arm-and-a-leg) say to go to the `Change / Port` setting menu to start the process, but I can't find this area anymore. Have they removed it?

Under `Phones`, my Sprint number is labeled `You Google Voice Number`, but I'm not sure if it's ported. I never paid any money to port it. How can I know?

[image: The <code>Phones</code> menu in Google Voice showing that my Sprint number is my Google Voice number]

At the end of this, I want to be sure that, if I cancel my Sprint plan, I'll still have the number accessible via Google Voice.

Comment: You may just want to wait a little bit. I hear they're getting ready to drop a new Google Voice very soon.

Comment: I would, but I'm moving to Kenya in two days, so I won't be able to do things with my Sprint number after that.

Comment: I know Sprint had some special deal with GV, but I don't quite recall what it was. I was Verizon until I switched to Google Fi, so I'm afraid I can't help. Hopefully someone else has a good answer.